# Modifying apache2.conf AllowOveride All gives 500 Internal server error

Tags: server, apache2, php, lamp

I'm trying to migrate a test website from a hosted domain to an OCI ubuntu 22 instance.
The instance works ok, i've installed apache2 and php. I also copied my files to the instance.
However, my .htaccess file was not taken into account (for once, i've configured in my .htaccess file to point the files to .php -- in order to get rid of the .php extension when trying to access a file on the webserver, and this didn't work on the oci instance).

I've read that i should modify the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file to:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

However, i did this, and after saving the file and restarting apache2, now i get "500 Internal Server Error" no matter which page in my website i try to access.

```
> Internal Server Error The server encountered an internal error or
> misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
> 
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to
> inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
> 
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log.
> 
> Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) Server at
```

This is the only modification I made. If i go back to the default configuration, with AllowOverride None, i get no error, but the .htaccess file in my /var/www/html/test01 (name of my test website) is not taken into account.

LE:

I checked the logs and it seems it actually sees the .htaccess file, however i get the following in the logs:

```
Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
DirectoryIndex home.php
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
```

I also tried removing RewriteEngine line, and now it gives `Invalid command 'RewriteCond'`

What is the problem?

LE2:

I solved it by `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: capital A for `All` Did you also activate `vhost_alias_module`? did you, at some point, do `sudo a2enmod rewrite`?

Comment: tried with capital A, did not work. I did not active vhost_alias_module, and did not do sudo a2enmode rewrite

Comment: What does your `/var/log/apache2/error.log` say about this?

Comment: Hmm, ok, actually it seems to be using the .htaccess file, however i get this error:
/var/www/html/test01/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration.

I am uploading .htaccess file here. This is the same one as the one on my hosted webserver and there it works